# Format the output of ls -lRA command using grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am trying to print only specific lines from the output based on keywords using grep

```
ls -RlA | grep foo | sed -n '1 p'
ls -RlA | grep bar | sed -n '1 p'
ls -RlA | grep foo_file
ls -RlA | grep bar_file
```

Is there a way to simplify these statements into just one command?

P.S: Order does not matter

Comment: Have you looked at the find command?

Comment: Yes I have. But, I want to print the ls -l output only related to the keywords "foo_file", "bar_file", "foo" and "bar". I don't think find would we useful to do that?

Comment: what part of the output are you looking for them? The filename? Add a full example to your question.

Comment: Yes. file (or directory name)

Comment: `grep -m 1 foo` is much more efficient than `grep foo | sed -n '1 p'`. Though using `ls` (a tool designed to generate output for human consumption) in scripts is generally a code smell to start with. See [Why you don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: And yes, you absolutely can use `find` with multiple patterns. Consider, for example, `find . '(' -name 'foo' -o -name 'bar' -o -name 'foo_file' -o -name 'bar_file' ')' -exec ls -l {} +`

Comment: **close**: unclear what you are trying to ask about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find all files or directories with the given names:

```
find . '(' -name foo -o -name bar -o -name foo_file -o -name bar_file ')' -ls
```

A more compact version using a regex:

```
find . -regex '.*/\(foo\|bar\|foo_file\|bar_file)' -ls
```

Same as above, but check that `foo_file` and `bar_file` are files, not directories:

```
find . '(' -name foo -o -name bar -o -name foo_file -type f -o -name bar_file -type f ')' -ls
```

Answer (score 1):

Here in one command.

```
ls -la **/{foo,bar,foo_file,bar_file}
```

You can also use `*` inside `{}`, such as `{*.txt,foo_*.zip}`.

Note that it will not work if one of the field inside `{}` is not found.